# Populate multiple lines of text field(example: Summary )based on choice field

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to figure out how to populate the multiple lines of text field value based on the choice field. I did try researching but was unable to find the answer. 
Say for example I have a value (ABC) in choice field , that should be populated when the user clicks on that into multiple lines of text (summary) field

Comment: the question and description provided is contradicting can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you using classic or modern experience in SharePoint Online?

Comment: @MihailPopa I am using classic experience

Comment: @Sunilsahu I am trying to do a calculated column on multiple lines of text. Also I need to make sure when the list is saved only a particular column should be sent out as an email